# How to use hard code to sort a string in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

i have a little kotlin app to format some text, i have input text (string) like:

```
    }, {
            "aliases": [ "Wave6" ],
            "objclass": "SpawnZombiesJitteredWaveActionProps",
            "objdata": {
                "Zombies": [ {
                        "Row": "1",
                        "Type": "RTID(mummy_armor1@ZombieTypes)"
                    }, {
                        "Row": "2",
                        "Type": "RTID(pharaoh@ZombieTypes)"
                    }, {
                        "Row": "4",
                        "Type": "RTID(mummy_armor2@ZombieTypes)"
                    } ]
            }
        }, {
```

and after some replace commands it becomes:

```
|6
|{{P|Conehead Mummy|2}}<sup>1</sup> {{P|Pharaoh Zombie|2}}<sup>2</sup> {{P|Buckethead Mummy|2}}<sup>4</sup> 
|None
|
|-
```

but i want it it be sorted in a scific way, not alphabetical or decimal, just a costom order, so i want the output to be like:

```
|6
|{{P|Conehead Mummy|2}}<sup>1</sup> {{P|Buckethead Mummy|2}}<sup>4</sup> 
{{P|Pharaoh Zombie|2}}<sup>2</sup> 
|None
|
|-
```

and i think it needs to be hardcoded, but im not shure how to do it

btw my replace commands are like `.replace("\\s*mummy_armor2@ZombieTyps\\s*", "buckethead mummy")` so i can edit a little but pls dont let me do too much it has 150+ rows

Comment: that input is in JSON. you should use JSON parsers instead of using replace commands

Comment: like how json it is from a EditText.text

Answer (score 0):

I think you won't be able to sort string properly. You should parse JSON to objects which are extending `Comparable<Object>` to override `compareTo` method which you will use to determine how you would like to sort.

Please take a look at [Ordering Documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-ordering.html).

Comment: uhh i dont understand

Comment: oh there is a doc didnt see that